# How do I LINQify this?

Tags: linq, resharper

Resharper says I can but I don't see how.  There are several examples of the form:

```
foreach (ItemType Item in ListOfItems)
    if (ConditionalInvolvingItem)
        Total += ItemProperty;
```

Of course I could make a sublist on the conditional and then sum the items in the sublist but this would be no clearer and would run slower.

Comment: But resharper will also convert it to linq for you.... just use alt-enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper is a handy tool, but keep in mind its suggestions aren't always necessarily more performant or self-explanatory. Such is the case here. It's really a toss-up. I'm sure you already have a LINQ statement in mind, but I'd imagine this example would look as such:

```
var Total = (from Item in ListOfItems
    where (ConditionalInvolvingItem)
    select ItemProperty).Sum();
```

Comment: I also just remembered that if you aren't dealing with non-numeric types, you'll need to use Aggregate instead of Sum and supply your own accumulator function. Keep that in mind when concerning readability's sake.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I see what I missed.

Answer (score 3):

```
var total = listOfItems
                .Where(item => ConditionalInvolvingItem(item))
                .Sum(item => item.Property);
```

Comment: +1. Serious question: at a glance, which is more understandable?

Comment: I wouldn't complain about the `foreach` in a code review, but that wasn't the question. The Linq version *is* more expressive of the intent, but which one you use is your call.

Comment: You both seem to have answered at the same time with basically identical answers.  Since you've got 100x the points he does I gave him the accepted answer since I can't accept both of you.